# Difference between the super keyword of javascript and java

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs

Even when using react, say using the older syntax, I thought the ***super*** keyword accesses the constructor of the Component class.
Is this true?

Comment: Code examples would be very beneficial in understanding what you want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `super` keyword in both Java and JS is a reference to the object's parent. You can access/call parent's constructors, methods, properties with this keyword.

```
class Cat extends Animal {
 
 Cat(){
  super(); // calls Animal's constructor
 }

 String toString() {
  return super.toString(); // calls toString() of Animal
 }
}
```

There are restrictions what you do with it, and the documentation is your best friend.

JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super

Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html